# how to extract list elements that meet specific criteria and get count for those elements in android

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I have a list of which contains information about vehicles and I would like to extract the count(total) of  vehicles with mileage over 10 000 . What is the best way to achieve that?

```
 private List<MyList> myListItems;

 myListItems= MyList.LoadListData();

 for (int i = 0; i <= myListItems.size(); i++)
{
            {  //myListItems.get(i).mileage().count()
                 myListItems.get(i).mileage() > 10 000;

            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0, size = myListItems.size(); i < size; i++){
     if(myListItems.get(i).mileage() > 10 000){
         total++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8:

```
long count = myListItems.stream()
                        .filter(v -> v.mileage() > 10_000)
                        .count();
```